# Usage of RebusTransactionScope

Tags: rebus, pre-build-event

I need clarification on using transaction scopes in Rebus.
In Configuration options I have o.HandleMessagesInsideTransactionScope();
Now Do I need to use the statement using scope=new RebusTransactionScope() in my Handlers or the Setup I have made will suffice.
In my Handler I do a database transaction and later send messages to other handlers for further processing.
I need all the processing in the hander to be atomic and hence be wrapped in a transaction scope.

I just need to know the right approach to achieving this.
Regards
Amour Rashid.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing two types of transaction scopes here: Rebus has its own transaction scope, which you can use like this:

```
using (var scope = new RebusTransactionScope())
{
    await bus.Send(oneMessage);
    await bus.Send(anotherMessage);

    // no messages have been sent at this point
    //
    // 
    // but when we do this  they will be sent
    await scope.CompleteAsync();
}
```

When you're in a Rebus handler, there's no need to use `RebusTransactionScope`, because the handler will have its own transaction scope, which gets completed after your code has finished executing without any exceptions.

The other transaction scope is a part of .NET. That's what you enable when you call

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Options(o => o.HandleMessagesInsideTransactionScope())
    .(...)
```

which will cause Rebus handlers to execute inside a `System.Transactions.TransactionScope`.

> (...) I need all the processing in the hander to be atomic (...)

Unfortunately, it can never be atomic*, because the queueing system and your database cannot be enlisted in the same transaction. I mean, they can PRETEND to be, by elevating your transaction to a DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION, using the two-phase commit protocol to orchestrate commits, but unfortunately distributed transactions are slow and come with a bunch of problems.

Generally, since Rebus ensures "at least once delivery" of messages, you're better off ensuring that your code is idempotent.

---

(*) at least in general, it can't